# Section and chapter problem

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I have a problem about section/chapter.

I'm writing a book and the final chapter is the exercises solution. To become better, I used `\chapter*{Solutions}`in this one and add it to the summary using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Solutions}}`.

But, there's a problem, because as I'm using the header to write or the chapter name, or the section name, the chapter before the Solutions chapter keeps "writing" in this one.

It's like this: the chapter before the Solutions one it's about inverse functions, then, when I compile the `.tex`, I see in the header's Solutions chapter the title: Inverse functions. But, I want to see: Solutions.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just created a new page style hahaha and it worked! Thank you anyway :)

Comment: The OP found a solution himself by using a different pagestyle.

Answer (score 1):

`\markboth` can be used to set the text for the header line, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Inverse functions}
  \section{Squaring and square root functions}
  \newpage
  Function A.
  \newpage   
  Function B.

  \chapter*{Solutions}
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{Solutions}}{\MakeUppercase{Solutions}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Solutions}
  \newpage
  Foo.
  \newpage
  Bar.
\end{document}
```

Another way is to disable the numbering via counter `secnumdepth`. This way the header line is automatically set and also the entry in the table of contents is given:

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Inverse functions}
  \section{Squaring and square root functions}
  \newpage
  Function A.
  \newpage
  Function B.

  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
  \chapter{Solutions}
  \newpage
  Foo.
  \newpage
  Bar.
\end{document}
```